# Groupby to Dataframe in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Basically, i use an excel file that contains thousands of data and I'm using pandas to read in the file.

```
import pandas as pd
agg = pd.read_csv('Station.csv', sep = ',')
```

Then what i did was i grouped the data accordingly to these categories,

```
month_station = agg.groupby(['month','StationName'])
```

the groupby will not be used for counting the mean, median or etc but just aggregating the data in terms of month and station name. *it's what the question wants*

Now, I would want to output the month_station into an excel file so first i would need to transfer the groupby into the dataframe.

I've seen examples:

```
pd.DataFrame(month_station.size().reset_index(name = "Group_Count"))
```

but the thing is, i don't require the size/count of my data but just grouping it in terms of month and station name which does not require count or sorts. I tried removing the size() and it gives me an error.

I just want the content of month_station to be ported into a dataframe so i could proceed and output as a csv file but it seemed complicated.

Comment: how about `set_index("your_index_name")`?

Comment: @RHSmith159 where would it be? pd.DataFrame(month_station.set_index("name"))?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I think it'd just be `new_df = month_station.set_index("name")`

Comment: @RHSmith159 it produces an error "Cannot access callable attribute 'set_index' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method"

Comment: Sorry but it is impossible to understand what you want without some input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

The nature of groupby is so that you can derive an aggregate calculation, such as mean or count or sum or etc. If you are merely trying to see on of each pair of month and station name, try this:

```
month_station = agg.groupby(['month','StationName'],as_index=False).count()
month_station = month_station['month','StationName']
```